# Listview Column with Sort Arrow has a different Backgroundcolor on Windows 10

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, windows-10

I'm currently using a C# `listview` with a custom sort arrow.

On Windows 10 the column with the sort icon gets a gray background, but it should not change the color. It should be the default backcolor and only the sort arrow should appear.

This sorting arrow behavior does not appear when i'm using the Windows Explorer Columns.

Sample Code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/734463/Sort-listview-Columns-and-Set-Sort-Arrow-Icon-on-C

Screenshot:
http://abload.de/img/sort_arrowiur3d.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The Bug has been fixed with the Windows 10 Build 10159.